# How to group lines and show every nth line of that group

Tags: bash, awk

This is the file:

```
-
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
-
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
line13
line14
-
line15
line16
line17
line18
line19
line20
line21
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
awk 'NR%6==1' file
```

It shows every 6th line:

```
-
line6
line11
line16
```

But I expect this:

```
line6
line12
line18
```

The file lines are grouped by `-` each 7th line as the example.

Comment: your command and the output shown for the given sample doesn't match... nor does the accepted answer produce the expected output you want..

Comment: @Sundeep I think the answer worked for me, because I'm seeing my actual file and data which are fine. I'll test it again later.

Comment: @Sundeep yes you're right. Thanks, I was writing that only in SO and forgot it might not work as expected to test. I edited. Regarding answers, you're right too. They don't give me the expected output.

Comment: @Sundeep yes you're right. Thanks, I was writing that only in SO and forgot it might not work as expected to test. I edited. Regarding answers, you're right too. They don't give me the expected output.

Comment: `awk 'NR%7==0'` would work for the sample input and expected output shown..

Comment: @Sundeep yes, I was just testing this too and got the same result a minute ago:)

Comment: The expected output you show is not the Nth line of each group as you said you wanted, it's every Nth line of the whole file. `line6` is the 6th line of the first group but `line12` is the 5th line of the second group and `line18` is the 4th line of the third group.

Comment: *"The file lines are grouped by - each 7th line as the example."* -- NO. It's every 8th line unless you ignore `line 1`. It is unclear what significance you are attaching to lines beginning with `'-'`? Do you want to reset counting at every `'-'` or do you just want to ignore them as your `awk` example does?

Answer (score 2):

you can solve it like this :

`awk '/^-/{group++;next} group && ((NR-group)%6==0){print}' file`

- '/^-/{group++;next}' - When a line starts with "-", increment the group counter and skip to the next line.
- 'group && ((NR-group)%6==0){print}' - If we are in a group (i.e., group is not 0) and the current line number minus the group number modulo 6 is 0, print the current line

Result :

```
line6
line12
line18
```

Comment: It shows lines 6, 13 and 20. Not 6, 12 and 18. Would you please check it again?

Comment: @Saeed thnx check it again ...

Comment: If the file does not end with a "-" separator, the last group will not be printed!

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to print the nth line of every group then it'd be:

```
$ awk -v n=6 '/^-/{c=0} c++ == n' file
line6
line13
line20

$ awk -v n=7 '/^-/{c=0} c++ == n' file
line7
line14
line21
```

Comment: Now you have to bring all that higher-math into it... But, good point. I'm still unclear on what he intends with the *"grouped by - ..."* description. Is that just a restatement of the file content, or some action he wants to take each time the `'-'` is encountered.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I THINK the OP has groups of lines separated by `-`s and they want to print the Nth line from each group but idk.

Answer (score 2):

For every line which is not the separator, increment a counter. If the incremented counter is divisible by 6, print the line:

```
awk '$0 != "-" && ++c % 6 == 0'
```